# What's the form of the subgroups of $(\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, abelian-groups, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be prime integer. I've read that every subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)^2$ has the form

\begin{equation}
(\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)^e\times U
\end{equation}

with $0\le e \le 2$ and $U$ a finite group. My question is: why?

**Some ideas:**

$\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a $p$-divisible group that has only finite subgroups. One idea could be: consider $H$ a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)^2$ and consider $D$ its maximal divisible subgroup. If $D\cong (\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)^e$ and has finite index in $H$, then we're done since divisible subgroups are always direct summands. But I don't know if (or why) the hypotheses are true.

Comment: The main step is to show that if $H $ is infinite then it contains a sequence $(a_n), p a_n = a_{n-1},a_1\ne 0,pa_1=0$. If it is infinite then take $f\in Aut(Q_p^2/Z_p^2)\cong GL_2(Z_p)$ such that $f(H)=Q_p/Z_p\times 0$. Then quotient $f(H)$ by $Q_p/Z_p\times 0$ to obtain a subgroup of $(Q_p/Z_p \times Q_p/Z_p)/(Q_p/Z_p \times 0)\cong Q_p/Z_p$.

Comment: I meant such that $f(a_n) = (p^{-n},0)$. The quotient $f(H)$ by $Q_p/Z_p\times 0$..

Comment: The existence of the sequence is ok, if $H$ is infinite. Now I try to interpret your hint: consider $K$ the subgroup generated by the sequence $(a_n)$: this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ via the map $a_n\mapsto p^{-n}$. This means that $K$ contins a copy of $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ as direct summand, since $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ is divisible. Hence I can work on $K/(\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p)$: if it is finite, I'm done. If it is infinite, I make the same reasoning done before.

Comment: Edit: the existence of that sequence is not ok, I still can't manage to prove it precisely.